# Unable to insert id into a table that belongs to a foreign key referenced table using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, serverless, claudia.js

I am building serverless application using node js and using claudia-api-builder as a framework to launch APIs in AWS.

In app.js file, i call the required api as

```
const ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
const api = new ApiBuilder();
module.exports = api;

api.post('/api/auth/validatephonenumber', async function (request) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        index.loadDatabase().then((db) => {
            resolve(loginController.validatePhonenumber(db, request));
        });
    });
});
```

Below is my code:

```
async function validatePhonenumber(db, request) {
return new Promise(
    async (resolve, reject) => {
        let emailid;            
        await db.EmailRegistration.sync().then(function () {
             emailid = db.EmailRegistration.findOne({
                where: { email: { [Op.eq]: mailid } },
                attributes: ['id'],
            });
        });
        if (emailid != null) {
            console.log(`email id: ${emailid.id}`);
            await db.ContactDetails.sync().then(function () {
                db.ContactDetails.findOrCreate({
                    where: { contactnumber: phnum },
                    defaults: { EmailRegistrationId: emailid.id },
                }).spread((contactdetails, created) => {
                    console.log(`contactdetails: ${contactdetails}`);
                    if (contactdetails !== null) {
                        resolve({ statuscode: indexController.statusCode.statusOK, contactdetails: contactdetails })
                    } else {
                        reject({ statuscode: indexController.statusCode.InternalServerError, message: 'phone number not created' });
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });
}
```

I am trying to add a emailregistrationid of EmailRegistration table into ContactDetails table as a foreign key reference. I am using sequelize with mysql, nodejs to achieve the desired results. But, i am getting below error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inmeeydb`.`ContactDetails`, CONSTRAINT `ContactDetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EmailRegistrationId`) REFERENCES `EmailRegistration` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Below is my EmailRegistration models file:

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const EmailRegistration = sequelize.define(
'EmailRegistration',
{
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: { min: 6 },
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(new Date(), 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a').format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a');
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,       
  },
},
{
  freezeTableName: true,
}
);

EmailRegistration.associate = function (models) {
    EmailRegistration.hasOne(models.ContactDetails,
        { foreignKey: 'EmailRegistrationId' }
    );
};

return EmailRegistration;
};
```

Below is my Contactdetails models file:

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const ContactDetails = sequelize.define(
'ContactDetails',
{
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
  contactnumber: { type: DataTypes.STRING(13), allowNull: false },
  isverified: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: false },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    get() {
      return moment.utc(new Date(), 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a').format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a');
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,        
  },
},
{
  indexes: [{ fields: ['contactnumber'], unique: true }],
},
{
  freezeTableName: true,
}
);

ContactDetails.associate = function(models) {
ContactDetails.belongsTo(models.EmailRegistration, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  hooks: true,
  foreignKey: { allowNull: false },
});
};   


return ContactDetails;
};
```

I tried to change the code as below with reference in both tables, but nothing worked.

```
ContactDetails.associate = function(models) {
    ContactDetails.belongsTo(models.EmailRegistration,
    { foreignKey: 'EmailRegistrationId' }
    );
};
```

Not able to analyze how to overcome the issue. This worked fine when i used nodejs with expressjs and had no issues. It fails to identify the EmailRegistrationId(that is missing in the query) in ContactDetails table and shows the output as

```
INSERT INTO `ContactDetails` (`id`,`contactnumber`,`isverified`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ('52974e07-8489-4101-ab71-6af874903290','+xxxxxxxxx',false,'2018-10-12 08:55:35','2018-10-12 08:55:35');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the configuration of your association. The `ContactDetails` model will now have a field called `emailregistrationid`

```
EmailRegistration.associate = function (models) {
  EmailRegistration.hasMany(models.ContactDetails);
};

ContactDetails.associate = function(models) {
  ContactDetails.belongsTo(models.EmailRegistration, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    hooks: true,
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'emailregistrationid'
      allowNull: false
    },
  });
}

ContactDetails.create({
  ...
  emailregistrationid: <some_valid_emailregistrationid>
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I indeed changed the code to implement it the way you had given. But the above code fails to add a column 'emailregistrationid' in ContactDetails table. It just creates the columns as mentioned in the models file. There is no reference to emailregistrationid in it. Kindly let me know what else needs to be changed.

Comment: Are you using migrations?

Comment: Currently, i am not using as i have just started to migrate the project and got struck in this issue.

Comment: Its failing to put a reference of EmailRegistration table in ContactDetails table, with whatever the code being changed to. Not quite understanding, what is happening?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.  After lot of debugging i found that, i was missing the  
    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
                if (db[modelName].associate) {
                    db[modelName].associate(db);
                }
            });                                                                                                      part in my index.js file. After adding that, along with the solution you suggested, it worked. Thanks once again.